# Unable to set Background only for UiImageView only

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uipickerview

Im trying to  give a background for an image view only as white. Following is my code.

```
dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [dataArray addObject:@"Knowledge"];
    [dataArray addObject:@"Client"];

    float screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    float pickerWidth = screenWidth * 3 / 4;

    float xPoint = screenWidth / 2 - pickerWidth / 2;

    pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    pickerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
    [pickerView setDataSource: self];
    [pickerView setDelegate: self];
    [pickerView setFrame: CGRectMake(xPoint, 200.0f, pickerWidth, 200.0f)];
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    [pickerView selectRow:2 inComponent:0 animated:YES];

    UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc]
                              initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 20, 300, 400)];
    [imageview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];
    [imageview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [imageview setBackgroundColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:imageview];
    [self.view addSubview: pickerView];
```

Im facing two problems while doing so,

1. The background colour is being applied for both UIImageView and  UiPickerView  thought I have specified specifically as [imageview setBackgroundColor: [UIColor whiteColor]]; when it has to be only for UiImage.
2. The alignment changes when the phone is in landscape mode though I have given a proper coordinates. How can I sort this out?

Comment: What you want exactly? here you are setting background color to white of imageview and nothing is wrong in it. so what is the isse?

Comment: the white color background is being set for both pickerview and imageview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set pickerview's background color like,

```
   pickerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor]; //desired color
```

hope this will help :)

Comment: I am not getting your need properly ? what you want exactly? do you need white background to pickerview?

Comment: and I want black background for picker view

Comment: and you can set background color as black color as per my answer instead of lightgraycolor. so your pickerview will get black background

Comment: Imageview doesnt have a background

Comment: I tried setting the background as black for pickerview but it doesnt work

Comment: why what happen when you set black?  `pickerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];` set like this

Comment: and which one is imageview? your screenshot have one whole background image, one picker view and one white color view(don't know what is this), so when you talking about image view then to which object you pointing out? your question is not clearly understandable !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
imageView.opaque = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundView];
```